# showing date variable's value correctly

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms, datetime-format

I defined some field for user to help him/her enter the date for specific reason,

that's the entity:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="order_date", type="datetime", length=20,nullable=true)
 * 
 * @NotBlank()
 */
private $orderDate;
```

that's the form:

```
->add('orderDate',null, ["label" => "courseorder.orderDate",'widget' => 'single_text', 'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'])
```

that's the twig code when is about to show the entire list:

```
<td>{{ courseOrder.orderDate|date('y/m/d') }}</td>
```

*BUT*
 when entering this date ->(2/7/97)
it saves this ->(11/1/97) to data base and show in index.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about `twig date format` [enter link description here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html)

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;

->add('orderDate', DateType::class, [
        'label_attr' => ['class' => 'your-label-class'],
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
        'translation_domain' => false,
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
 ])
```

When show date form in your view:

```
<td>{{ courseOrder.orderDate|date('Y/m/d') }}</td>
```

Comment: __Explain__ what changes have you made.

Comment: Are You understand?

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse the format when **entering** the date (the form) with the format when **showing** the date (Twig).

In your form, you are using this:

```
->add('orderDate', null, [
    "label" => "courseorder.orderDate",
    'widget' => 'single_text', 
    'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
])
```

so the system is expecting you to insert the value like "2018-07-07" (when you're using the "single_text" widget). If you want to change the format when entering the  value, you should change the form field configuration to the desired format.